# fprintf in assembly and stdout

Tags: assembly, x86, libc, intel-syntax

In order to call `fprintf` from assembly code, I write the following

```
; push arguments...
push dword [stdout] ; given from "extern stdout"
call fprintf
; clean stack..
```

And it works just fine.

However, I would expect that I need to write `push dword stdout` because stdout is already a pointer (`FILE*`). Doing so gives me "wrong stdio handle error". Why is that?

Comment: `stdin` is defined externally as a `FILE *` . `push dword stdout` is pushing the address of `stdin` which is a pointer to a `FILE *`. So it actually acts like `FILE **`  (a pointer to a pointer). `push dword [stdout]` pushes the contents at `stdout` onto the stack which is a `FILE *`

Comment: Seems weird. Why don't we `call [fprintf]` then? hehe

Comment: Because the label`fprintf` is a pointer to the actual function already. `call [fprintf]` would use the first 4 bytes (32-bits) of the actual function `fprintf` as the address to jump to.